# After updating to windows 2004 my LocalHost:3000 is not working

Tags: reactjs, windows, vue.js, windows-update

I have updated my windows machine to the new windows update 2004. After the update, I am not able to open my localhost:3000. As a web dev, I do work a lot with React and Vue and if my localhost doesn't work I am finished. It this context want to add that before the update all ports were opening fine.

Comment: explain what you mean "doesn't work". we need more context to help you debug

Comment: The terminal says "starting a development server" and in the browser when I visit LocalHost:3000 or LocalHost:8080 it just loads. nothing happens there

Comment: what does the browser say when you visit 3000? and how are you starting the server?

Comment: The browsers just load again and again.. I am starting the server from terminal(git-bash)

Comment: with what command? `npm run start`?

Comment: yup it was "npm start" for react and "npm run dev" for vuejs

Comment: try a different port? `PORT=3003 npm run start`

Comment: have tried to run that on a different port. also, I have individually killed the running port then try again. But still no success